# Ошибка при подключении через psql

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, localhost, psql

Установил posgresql исходя из инструкции [ubuntu инструкция](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE_ubuntu_server/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/postgresql#%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)
Прописал нужные параметры в файле так же, как в инструкции Сейчас при попытке подключиться через psql все хорошо.

При попытке подключения через pgadmin с аналогичным пользователем получаю ошибку

> FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL on FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off

Погуглил, советуют прописать в pg_hba.conf не строку как указана в инструкции, а

```
local   all    postgres    127.0.0.1  md5
```

в таком случае не могу подключиться из консоли выдает ошибку:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Нет такого файла или каталога
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Подскажите, как довести до того, чтобы я мог создавать на сервере свои базы, таблички и работать с ней?

Comment: А вы обе с строки оставили в кинфиге ?

Comment: Нет, только одну

Comment: А вы обе напиишите. каждая строка отвечает за свое. та что была за отдачу через unix сокет. А вторая через tcp/ip (в пределах локальной машины)

Comment: нет не то это, не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local   all    postgres    127.0.0.1  md5
```

Строка указана дважды некорректно. Если вы делали `reload` - будет сообщение в логе и этот файл использоваться не будет. Если вы пытались сделать `restart` - база выключится и не запустится с ошибкой что-то вроде такой:

```
2018-12-07 14:15:07.271 MSK [7544] LOG:  invalid authentication method "127.0.0.1"
2018-12-07 14:15:07.271 MSK [7544] CONTEXT:  line 100 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf"
2018-12-07 14:15:07.271 MSK [7544] FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
```

Потому что `local` - это `unixsock`, у него не может быть IP адреса.

Вторая же ошибка здесь в самом адресе: IP обязан быть указан с маской сети.

```
invalid IP mask "md5": Name or service not known
```

---

Неясно что в конечном результате оказалось у вас в `pg_hba.conf`

Если вы хотите доступ только по паролю на локальном хосте, то вам нужны 3 строки:

```
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Для `unixsock`, `ipv4` и `ipv6` соответственно.

Обратите так же внимание, что сопровождающий пакетов предполагает, что у пользователя `postgres` есть неинтерактивный доступ к базе для скриптов. Соответственно если вы заблокируете доступ паролем - что-нибудь можно отломать и имеет смысл разместить в `homedir` пользователя `postgres` файл [`.pgpass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) с актуальным паролем.